# When do class members use smart pointers or objects

Tags: c++, class, object, smart-pointers

For example:

```
class Teacher{
 // ...
}


class Student{
   string name;
   Teacher math_teacher; // or use: std::share_ptr<Teacher> math_teacher;

}
```

Different students may have the same math teacher and I think they should share the same theacher. But I don't know whether smart points are better than objects?

And when do class members use smart pointers or objects?

Thanks!

Comment: Smart pointers are "smart" because they manage *ownership* (the lifecycle of the object).  For non-ownership situations, possibly a non-owning (non-smart) pointer is reasonable.  Sometimes an identifier (such as a string or uuid) that is passed to a manager object to retrieve a pointer or reference to a managed object is reasonable.

Comment: They do that when, after analyzing your program's requirements and how it should work, you reach the conclusion that your class members should be smart pointers instead of objects. This is a decision that ***you*** must make, as a C++ developer, based on your understanding of the fundamental differences between two approaches, and what it means for your program.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is to make the code as simple as possible.

So, for example, if you have a string as class member, like the student's name, you would definitely use `std::string`, and *not* a smart pointer to it:

```
class Student { 
    ...
    std::string m_name; // *not* std::shared_ptr<std::string> m_name !!
};
```

On the other hand, if you need to represent shared ownership, like in your teacher-student example, using a `std::shared_ptr` would be a better choice:

```
class Student { 
    ...
    std::shared_ptr<Teacher> m_teacher;
};
```

In this case, a single `Teacher` instance is shared among different `Student`s.

Moreover, if you can guarantee that the lifetime of the `Teacher` instance is appropriate, i.e. it's longer than that of its `Student`s, you can even simply use a raw *observing* pointer:

```
class Student { 
    ...
    // Raw observing pointer to Teacher.
    // Note: Pay attention to the Teacher instance lifetime.
    Teacher* m_teacher;
};
```

Comment: I like to apply much the same "rules" that I would when deciding whether some field in a database needs to be normalised, though that only really works if you have RDBMS experience.

Comment: "as simple as possible" -- but no simpler. Attributed to Albert Einstein.